# ${\cal N}=2$ SUSY Multiplet

Tags: particle-physics, supersymmetry, helicity, supersymmetric-particles

In [https://www.physics.uci.edu/~tanedo/files/notes/SUSYXD.pdf](https://www.physics.uci.edu/%7Etanedo/files/notes/SUSYXD.pdf), on page 47,  I found that for ${\cal N}=2$ SUSY (massless representation), we start with a state $|\Omega\rangle$ with helicity $\lambda_0=0$ and then apply the SUSY generators, we have 2 states
$$a_1^\dagger|\Omega\rangle; \ \ \ a_2^\dagger|\Omega\rangle $$
Both of the above states are having helicities $\lambda=\lambda_0+1/2=1/2$. Then according to the notes we have
$$a_2^\dagger a_1^\dagger|\Omega\rangle= a_1^\dagger a_2^\dagger|\Omega\rangle=|\text{State with }\lambda=1\rangle$$

I do not understand equality in the above expression, since the SUSY generators are fermionic in nature, should not $a_1^\dagger a_2^\dagger=-a_2^\dagger a_1^\dagger$?

Comment: The text isn't saying the states are equal, just that they are equal up to multiplication by a constant - since what you're saying about the anticommutativity is true.

Comment: @NiharKarve would you elaborate on that...

Comment: As you said, one gives $|\lambda_0+1\rangle$, the other gives $-|\lambda_0+1\rangle$. We don't really care because the purpose of this exercise is to find a basis for the representation space and either is a perfectly good basis vector.

Comment: @NiharKarve Okay thanx...